# Invariant problem starting with the sequence $1,2, ... ,100$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, invariance

> Initially, we are given the sequence $1,2, ... ,100$. Every minute, we erase any two numbers $u$ and $v$ and replace them with the value $uv + u + v$. Clearly, we will be left with just one number after $99$ minutes. Does this number depend on the choices that we made?

I think that the last number will be $$5050 + \sum_{i}u_iv_i$$ where $u_i$ and $v_i$ are the numbers picked at the $i$'th minute, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

It would seem that at each step the sum will be increased by the product $uv$. Is there an invariant here?

Before the first step the sum will be $$1+ \dots+ 100$$ after removing $u$ and $v$ it will be $$1+ \dots +\hat{u}+ \dots+ \hat{v}+ \dots +100 + uv + u +v = 1+ \dots +100 +uv$$ where the $\hat{u}$ means that we omit $u$. So after $99$ steps the sum will be $$1+ \dots + 100 + \sum_{i=1}^{99}u_iv_i = 5050 + \sum_{i}^{99}u_iv_i.$$

Comment: Start with a small set, say $1,2,3,4$.  What do you get if you combine $1$ and $2$, then $3$ and $4$.  What happens if instead you combine $1$ and $3$, then $2$ and $4$?

Comment: You will always end up with $119$ if you start with $1,2,3,4$ @MattGroff

Comment: So then you just need some way of writing what your sum is equal to at each step.

Comment: Well isn't it just $$5050 + \sum_{i}^{k}u_iv_i$$ where $k$ is the $k$'th step? @MattGroff

Answer (score 4):

$uv + u + v = uv + u + v + 1 - 1 = (u+1)(v+1) - 1$.

For the numbers $(u+1)(v+1) - 1$ and $w$; we get $ ((u+1)(v+1) - 1)w + ((u+1)(v+1) - 1) + w = (u+1)(v+1)(w+1) - 1 $. If we continue with this idea, our result is

$$(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1)\cdots (a_{100} + 1) - 1 = 101! - 1.$$

Here, $\{ a_1 , a_2 , \dots , a_{100} \} = \{ 1, 2, \dots , 100 \}$. The result does not depend on the order of selection of the numbers.

Comment: What is $w$? @scarface

Comment: $w$ is any of the numbers we'll be processing, like $u$ and $v$.

Comment: But what if after the first pick $u,v$ you take something different and not $(u+1)(v+1)-1$ and $w$? You could take $w$ and some $c$. This relies on you picking always $(u+1)(v+1)-1$ after you've first picked $u$ and $v$. @scarface

Comment: @Sehat if $x=(a+1)(b+1)-1$ then $x+1=(a+1)(b+1)$ this is the key to the process. If you pick an uncombined number $a$ then $(a+1)$ will appear, but if you take an already combined number $(a+1)(b+1)\cdots(k+1)-1$ then $(a+1)(b+1)\cdots(k+1)$ will appear.